# Инверсная кинематика и точка соприкосновения

Tags: unity3d

Делаю в Unity управление персонажем через инверсную кинематику. Подскажите каким образом точка на которую завязана ИК соотносится с моделью? Мне нужно схватиться персонажем за ручку шкафчика, а в другой момент повернуть кран. Рука попадает не в то место где мне нужно производить действие, как это решается? В документации используется корректирующий объект и анимация, но мне надо из кода делать подстройку хватаясь за центр коллайдера с поворотом относительно поворота коллайдера.